# Delta in Impala SQL

Tags: sql, impala

Hi I have a below table where i need to get the delta values for a column.How can i do this in Impala SQL.

## Table

```
System  Records
ABC      200
CFG      100
POK      400
```

Result Expected

Table with additional column showing the delta value.

## Table

```
System  Records  Delta
ABC      200      null
CFG      100      -100 
POK      400       300
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So, you need a column that specifies the ordering.  Once you have that, the rest is handled by `lag()`:

```
select system, records,
       (records - lag(records) over (order by ?)) as delta
from t;
```

The `?` is for the column that specifies the ordering.